# Can not compare date using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue. I can not compare todays date with previous date using Angular.js/Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
 var today=new Date();
 if(today >= new Date($scope.date1.split("-").reverse().join(","))){
    alert('Please select todays date or upcoming date');
 }
```

Here i am getting `$scope.date1` value like this `2016-10-18` format.Here i could not compare while date is `2016-10-18` .Here i need while selected date is previous date of todays date that alert will display.Please help me.

Comment: You know `"2016-10-18".split('-').reverse().join(',')` becomes `"18,10,2016"` which isn't any kind of date format

Comment: `new Date('2016-10-18')` seems to create the correct `Date` instance just fine. Not sure at all what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Phil : But while i am taking date like `2016-10-06` this ,its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date($scope.date1.split("-").reverse().join(","))` will not create a valid date.

```js
//Pass the string directly
var nDate = new Date('2016-10-18'); 
var today = new Date();
if (today >= nDate) {
  console.log('Please select todays date or upcoming date');
}
```

Comment: @ Satpal : Its showing alert even input is todays date also `i.e-2016-10-19` which should not come.

Comment: @subhra, Time is also considered, `new Date()` will consider current date and time where as `new Date('2016-10-18')` will set date with timezone offset

Comment: So in this case how can i do this. Here only input is date.

Comment: @ Satpal : Can you take date value as `2016-10-19`  and check ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare dates as you are doing.

When you initialize date object with `new Date()`, it is set with current time.

So

```
var today = new Date("2016-10-19"); //----> current date here
var anothertoday = new Date();
```

shall never be the same

```
anothertoday > today //-----> true
```

The above expression evaluates to true because if you see the time of both the dates

```
today.getHours() //---> 0
anothertoday.getHours() //---> current time shall be displayed
```

To compare it on the basis of only `date` you need to set time of `anothertoday` to `0` by `anothertoday.setHours(0,0,0,0)`

Now the above expression should evaluate to `false`

```
anothertoday > today //---->false
```

So in your case your code should be similar to this

```
var today = new Date();
$scope.date1 = "2016-10-18";
$scope.datearr = $scope.date1.split("-");
var yesterday = new Date($scope.datearr[0],$scope.datearr[1] - 1,$scope.datearr[2]);
today.setHours(0,0,0,0); //----> set time to 0 hours
if(today > yesterday)
   console.log("Please select todays date or upcoming date");
```